# Showing $S^2$ and $\overline{Y}$ are independent: seeking a solution to this textbook problem

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, variance, mean, independence

In *An Introduction to Generalized Linear Models* by Dobson and Barnett, exercise 1.4b&c is as follows:

> Let $Y_1,...,Y_n$ be independent random variables each with the distribution $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$. Let $\overline{Y}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_i$ and $S^2=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(Y_i-\overline{Y})^2$. ...
>
> b. Show that $S^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}[\sum_{i=1}^{n}(Y_i-\mu)^2-n(\overline{Y}-\mu)^2]$
>
> c. From (b) it follows that $\sum(Y_i-\mu)^2/\sigma^2 = (n-1)S^2/\sigma^2+[(\overline{Y}-\mu)^2n/\sigma^2]$. **How does this allow you to deduce that** 
>    $\overline{Y}$ **and** $S^2$ **are independent?**

My problem is that I don't see how the equation in c allows me to answer the question in bold.

I'm aware of how to prove the 2 being independent in general ([it has been asked before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47350/proof-of-the-independence-of-the-sample-mean-and-sample-variance?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)).

Moreover, when I look at the [solutions](https://www.crcpress.com/downloads/C9500/C9500_Solutions.pdf) they say:

> (c) and (d) follow from results on p.10

On page 10 the closest thing of use is the chi-square distribution's reproductive property, which *isn't* an if and only if statement, so I don't think it can be used here.

So my question is, **how does the equation in c) help to prove independence?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what the authors have in mind, but the closest solution I can think of using (c) is to apply [Cochran's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochran%27s_theorem). Have you covered that, or maybe a special case of it?

Here's the proof using that:

Let $Z_i = \frac{Y_i - \mu}{\sigma}$ so $Z_i \sim \mathcal N(0, 1)$ and $\bar Z \sim \mathcal N(\mu, \sigma^2/n)$. Note that
$$
\left(\frac{Y_i - \bar Y}{\sigma}\right)^2 = \left(\frac{Y_i - \mu}{\sigma} - \frac{\bar Y - \mu}{\sigma}\right)^2 = \left(Z_i - \bar Z\right)^2.
$$
Now (c) tells us
$$
\sum_i Z_i^2 = \sum_i (Z_i - \bar Z)^2 + n\bar Z^2
$$
which we can write as $\newcommand{\one}{\mathbf 1}$
$$
Z^T Z = Z^T \left(I - \frac 1n \one \one^T\right)Z + Z^T\left(\frac 1n  \one \one^T\right) Z.
$$
$I - \frac 1n \one \one^T + \frac 1n \one \one^T =I$ and both are idempotent so Cochran's theorem lets us conclude that $\sum_i (Y_i - \mu)^2 \perp n(\bar Y - \mu)^2$ and the rest follows.

$\square$

Could that be what they're going for?

Comment: Makes sense to me. Reading ahead, the author's ask a similar question in exercise 2.3 ('...using similar methods to exercise 1.3...') and they skip the solution out in the pdf. But, your approach works in 2.3 too.

Comment: @user1108 glad this helped. Either way, it's a good bet Cochran's theorem will come up at some point in a linear models book (and in fact this is a linear model already in that $\frac 1n \mathbf 1 \mathbf 1^T$ is the hat matrix for the intercept-only regression giving $\hat Z = \bar Z \mathbf 1$)